# Django - authentication only with the email

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to make a custom authentication where I login only with the e-mail address without password. I searched over internet but I don't find a good answer. I'm new in Django maybe this is the reason for why I can't find a solution. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: can you explain "only with email address"? Just entering an email is sufficient or should it send an email each time with a one-time login link?

Comment: What `without password` means?

Comment: i want in django admin the password field to not be required. some users to login only with the username or the email. can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Django `django.contrib.auth` has `authenticate`, `login` methods. If you just want login the user using only `email`, then get the `User` object using email and call `login` method

Example

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SomeLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = User.objects.get(email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
        if user:
            auth_login(request, user)
```

But I don't recommend it. You should validate user using mechanism like password or OTP that's where `authenticate` method comes